# Fixed points of absolute set difference

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fixed-points

Let $\mathbb N = \{0,1,2,\dots \}$ and define the map $D:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb N) \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$ as

$$D(A) = \{|a_2-a_1| : \space (a_1, a_2)\in A^2\}$$

How to characterize the fixed points of $D$?

Comment: I sort of came up with the answer while posting the question, but I decided to post it anyhow with my solution. Maybe some day someone else stumbles upon this mapping and wonders about its fixed points. Also to perhaps have my solution checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty set will be one. If $\emptyset \neq A = D(A)$, then $0\in A$. If $A$ has two nonzero elements $x$ and $y>x$, then $y-x \in A$. In fact, we can subtract $x$ from $y$ as many times as the result stays positive and still the result stays in $A$. That is, we can reduce $y$ $\pmod x$. Further, we can reduce $x$ modulo the natural number $ r = (y \pmod x) \in A$. This sounds like the Euclidian algorithm and leads to the fact that $\gcd(x,y) \in A$. This can be done for any two elements of $A$, so the $\gcd$ of the total set $A$ must also lie in $A$.

When dealing with $\gcd$'s we usually get the whole ideal generated by it, i.e $d\mathbb Z$.  On the other hand, $D$ doesn't create any bigger numbers than there are already in $A$, so $D(A) \subset \overline M := \{0,1,2,\dots, M\}$ where $M=\sup A$ (and $\overline M$ is understood to be $\mathbb N$ if $A$ is unbounded and $\emptyset$ if $A$ is $\emptyset$).

Let's now make the guess:

$$\{A \subset \mathbb N : D(A)=A\} = \{A\subset \mathbb N : A=\gcd(A)\mathbb Z \cap \overline {\sup A}\}$$

**Proof**

"$\subset$":

Let's assume $D(A)=A$. If $A=\emptyset$, we are done, since the empty set is on the right hand side. So, let $A\neq \emptyset$ and $d=\gcd(A)$.

Let's first prove the inclusion $A \subset d\mathbb Z \cap \overline {\sup A}$.
Of course $A \subset \overline {\sup A}$.
We get that $d\in A$ by the Euclidian algorithm (do it for any two numbers in $A$ to get some number $d_1$; then do it for $d_1$ and another number of $A$ to get $d_2$ that is closer to $d$; the $\gcd$ of $A$ can be reached in finite number of steps (the numbers d_k decrease to $d$)).
If there is $x\in A$ that isn't a multiple of $d$, then $\gcd(d, x)<d$ but then $\gcd(A)<d$, a contradiction.
Hence $A \subset d\mathbb Z$.

Let's then prove the inclusion $d\mathbb Z \cap \overline {\sup A} \subset A$:
Let $x\in d\mathbb Z \cap \overline {\sup A}$ so $x=kd, k\in \mathbb N$ and $x \leq \sup A$. Now there is an $a\in A$ with $a\geq x$.
Since $d=\gcd(A)$, $a=td, t\in \mathbb N$. Take $d$ away from $a$ $\space \space$ $t-k (\geq0)$ times to get that $x\in D^{t-k}(A)=A$.

"$\supset$":

Assume $A=d\mathbb Z \cap \overline {\sup A}$. Again if $A=\emptyset$, $D(A)=A$ and we're done. So assume $A\neq \emptyset$. We need to show $D(A)=A$.

The inclusion $A\subset D(A)$ is clear, because $0=0d\in d\mathbb Z \cap \overline {\sup A} = A$, so every $a \in A$ is gotten as $|a-0|$ with $D$.

Let's then prove $D(A) \subset A$ and for that let $x\in D(A)$. So $x=a_2 - a_1$ for some $a_1, a_2 \in A$ (wlog assume $a_2\geq a_1$). From the assumption we get that $a_j=k_jd$ with $k_j \in \mathbb N$ for $j=1,2$. Hence,

$$x=(k_2-k_1)d.$$

But this means that $x\in d\mathbb Z$. Because in addition $0\leq x=a_2-a_1 \leq a_2 \leq \sup A$, we have $x \in \overline{sup A}$. These, with the assumption $d\mathbb Z \cap \overline {\sup A} = A$, mean that $x\in A$.

Comment: There is also the special case $A=\{0\}$ and how $\gcd(0)$ even is defined, but we can decide $\gcd(0) = 0$ (although $\gcd(0, x)=x$) to make the formula agree also then.